# Laravel DB Query insert list of ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

How I can insert a list of ids with DB query without use foreach.

**example with foreach :**

```
$ids=[1,3,5];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    DB::Table('user')->insert(['name'=>'test','user_id'=>$id]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `array_map`;

```
$ids = [1, 3, 5];
$data = array_map(function ($id) {
    return ['name' => 'test', 'id' => $id];
}, $ids);

DB::table('user')->insert($data);
```

Comment: This solution will make me connect to the database only once, Thanks